# Relation between LCD best resolution and actual font size (pixel)

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, lcd

Where can we find a table with LCD size and best resolution? Like [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution). It's good, but when I only know the LCD monitor is 22", it's hard to find what exactly resolution should I use.

Also, I found that under best resolution: 19" for 1280x1024, 20" for 1600x1200, 22"(wide) for 1920x1080. The default windows font size looks biggest in 19" and smallest in 20". So that makes it harder to read in 20" monitor. And even I have choice for 19" or 22", I will go for 19" since the text looks bigger.

Is there any website/table make this actual font(text) size comparison?

Any way to adjust the OS-wise font size when using 20" LCD? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [DPI list](http://www.notebookcheck.net/DPI-Fineness-of-Displays.1310.0.html) which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike LCD TVs, LCD computer monitors do not have a standard resolution, even in relation to monitor size. Therefore, there is no way to provide a direct table from screen size > resolution. It's simply not possible.

**You should run your LCD monitor at whatever it's native resolution is.** You can figure this out from either the manual, or if you've lost it, then it should be somewhere on the OSD (play around with the monitor buttons).

Comment: Also, if Windows can identify the monitor then it will usually set the proper resolution, or it will offer that resolution as the maximum. If it doesn't, then select the maximum available resolution setting and click Apply. It the monitor can display the screen, fine. If not, it will revert to the previous setting and you can try the maximum-minus-one setting. Repeat this with ever decreasing resolution until the monitor can display the screen. Done.

Comment: @torbengb: And of course, make sure you don't have black bars on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

IME, the 19" monitor is therefore worse than the 22" monitor. The probable reason the text looks bigger is because it has a larger *dot pitch*. The dot pitch is the space between the pixels, and the smaller the pitch, the better, because you have a higher resolution screen for the same screen size. If you're using the same computer to test them, the [DPI](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Dots_per_inch) (dots per inch) probably didn't change when you changed your monitors. If you want the text to be bigger, just adjust the DPI for the screen. Here's a guide to that in [Windows](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Change_DPI_Size_in_Windows_7_25979243) or [Linux](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=20976).

Comment: You are exactly correct. Since 19" and 22" probably use same pixels to display a single character, which makes text in 22" looks smaller. I also know adjusting DPI works, but on Windows XP, adjust to 125% enlarge most of window control and text, but not for everything, like some size-customized windows program, which makes the bottom right 'OK' or 'cancel' button disappears. Thanks though.

Comment: @Stan: In Windows XP, the operating system simply resizes text, then tells the application to resize it's windows and controls. If the program is not designed to do this, then you have problems. In Windows Vista/7, if the program has not explicitly stated that they can handle high DPIs, then the operating system will resize the whole window like an image, making it work, but causing small artifacts.